# Unable to read data from Spanner table into Spark Job running on Dataproc cluster

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-spanner, spark3

I'm doing an integration wherein I'm trying to read data from a simple gcp spanner table into Spark job which is running on a dataproc cluster. For this integration I'm using google-cloud-spanner-jdbc dependency in pom.xml. Though there is no exception when job runs, the problem is, ***it returns an empty dataframe*** with correct column names. I'm interested in using spark's native approach rather than standard JDBC connection.

PS: I have already done this integration using standard JDBC approach.

Below is the code snippet:

```
val spannerOptions = Map(
      "url" -> s"jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/$projectId/instances/$instanceId/databases/$databaseId",
      "driver" -> "com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcDriver"
    )

 val df = spark.read.format("jdbc")
      .options(spannerOptions)
      //.option("dbtable", tableName) ---> tried this as well. 
      .option("query", "select * from emp")
      //.schema(schema) --> tried specifying the schema as well. 
      .load()

    df.show()
```